# Why does marked-as-duplicate suggest asking a new question rather than editing?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

All the other close reasons suggest editing the question to fit the rules if possible, but questions closed as duplicates should be reasked instead.

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Why is this and why is it a good idea when that makes extra work for the asker?

Comment: What are you talking about editing?  The Duplicate target question where this message appears or a hypothetical question that was already asked and closed as a duplicate?

Comment: I mean a question closed as a duplicate, which has the message: "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question." I.e. why shouldn't the question be edited to ask the particular question that isn't answered, which may be as simple as adding some requirements.

Comment: Related on MSE [“Please ask a new question” encourages question repetition for duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174744/please-ask-a-new-question-encourages-question-repetition-for-duplicates)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The message you are seeing is geared towards users who did not ask the question.  the message that the OP gets is slightly different.  The message that the asker gets reads

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, **please edit this question to explain how it is different** or ask a new question.

I don't know why they are invited to asking a new question, possibly that phrase should be removed since it is almost never correct to ask a new question when your question gets closed, but users are already encouraged to edit their question when it is closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Ok, didn't know it showed up different. Still doesn't explain why it should be any different for duplicates than other close reasons though.

Comment: @otus in all of the linked questions on MSE that I found double checking what I thought, none really address why the `or ask a  new question` is mentioned.