# Make marked-as-duplicate "guidance for next time" link to search help

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, search

If a question is closed as duplicate, you wind up with something at the top of the question like:

> This question already has an answer here:
>
> *Link To Other Question* 5 answers

Then at the bottom you get:

> marked as duplicate by *Sleepy*, *Grumpy*, *Sneezy*, *Dopey*, *Sneezy* *Time-And-Date*
>
> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

No help center link there.  But apparently if you are the user in question, you get a suggestion to edit to make your question unique:

[Why does marked-as-duplicate suggest asking a new question rather than editing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258300/why-does-marked-as-duplicate-suggest-asking-a-new-question-rather-than-editing)

**but** as advice goes...might it be nice if the bottom marked-as-duplicate help box always had a link to "how to search on StackOverflow"?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

I'm imagining people who do their keyword searching on Google... and if they come up short go straight to "Ask Question" without realizing they can search in a language tag, etc.

This basically fits into the category of the thing I'd want to tell every user asking a duplicate question (*"learn to search better!"*) so that makes it a good candidate for being in that box.  I'd suggest it's worth advertising enough to put it in the bottom box for everyone--not just the asker, to give search features more exposure.

Comment: Google/Bing/whatever provide better search results than SO for me - I don't think adding that link would be helpful in current state of search and suggested help page. (Note that "related" links are generally way more helpful, but they are present only after the fact of asking question).