# Marked as duplicate close message should include edit

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, duplicate-questions

When a message is closed as a dupe the text currently reads:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

However, this seems like a sub-optimal response as the text could include links to edit and vote to re-open your question. I'm not the best with words so I won't suggest any alternate  text here.

Can/should this be implemented?

Comment: Is this message shown on *your* question? (I believe message is different between OP and everyone else... and the request is already "status-complete")

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Shown on someone else's question, I just assumed the message would be the same because of how it read.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If the messages are still the same then [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258300/why-does-marked-as-duplicate-suggest-asking-a-new-question-rather-than-editing?rq=1) answers my request...